# Problem 6 chapter 5 from PMA Rudin

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose

(a) $f$ is continuous for $x\geqslant 0$,

(b) $f'(x)$ exists for $x>0$,

(c) $f(0)=0$,

(d) $f'$ is monotonically increasing.

Put $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x}\quad (x>0)$ and prove that $g$ is monotonically increasing.

Unfortunately I have not any ideas. Can anyone show the proof of this problem?

Comment: Show that g'(x) is always non-negative.

Comment: An aside: does Rudin actually use the term "monotonically increasing"/ Is there any reason for the redundant "monotonic"? I just want to be sure he isn't interpreting it as "strictly" or something.

Comment: @YunusSyed, I know that if we show that $g'(x)$ is always non-negative then we done. But I also can't do that.

Comment: Try showing if y > x then g(y) > g(x)

Comment: @YunusSyed, How to use condition (d) that $f'$ is increasing?

Comment: Can you calculate $g'(x)$? If so, set it to be non-negative, and see if you can get an inequality that you can work with (one that involves $f$ in some way).

Comment: Niote that if $f$ is twice differentiable, this follows from the fact that $f'' \ge 0$, which must be true since $f'$ is increasing. Now to figure out how to adapt that to the more general case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, $g$ is differentiable in $(0,\infty)$ with $g'(x)=\frac{xf'(x)-f(x)}{x^2}$. Fix $x\in(0,\infty)$. By the Mean Value Theorem there is some $y\in(0,x)$ such that $f'(y)=\frac{f(x)}{x}$. Since $f'$ is increasing, $f'(x)\geq\frac{f(x)}{x}$, and this implies $xf'(x)\geq f(x)$ and finally $g'(x)\geq0$. Thus, $g'(x)\geq0$ for all $x$ showing that $g$ is increasing.

Comment: Dear sranthrop! Very nice solution. Thank you very much!